# How to make 2 sql queries 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 reasonably simple queries that i need to make one. Im just having a mental blank today.

```
SELECT max(StatusReportID) 
  FROM dbo_VehicleStatusReport
```

and

```
SELECT StatusReportID, StatusReportTime, CarNumber, VehicleID, 
       DriverNumber, DriverID, VehicleStatus, LocationX, LocationY, 
       Speed, Direction, InvalidGPS 
  FROM dbo_VehicleStatusReport 
 WHERE StatusReportID > " & MaxStatusReportID2 & "
```

where  & MaxStatusReportID2 & is the result from the first query minus 3000 (-3000)

Comment: basically whats below, the bit thats throwing me is the - 3000

Comment: Can you explain what relevance the 3000 has?

Comment: Like as in 'find the newest 2999 status reports'?

Comment: @Nat maybe, but I want to be sure that is the purpose before explaining the problem with that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just wrap it on a subquery,

```
SELECT StatusReportID, 
       StatusReportTime, 
       CarNumber, 
       VehicleID, 
       DriverNumber, 
       DriverID, 
       VehicleStatus, 
       LocationX, 
       LocationY, 
       Speed, 
       Direction, 
       InvalidGPS 
FROM   dbo_VehicleStatusReport 
WHERE  StatusReportID > 
       ((SELECT max(StatusReportID) FROM dbo_VehicleStatusReport) - 3000)
```

Comment: I think you forgot about the `3000`...

Comment: but i need to have (SELECT max(StatusReportID) FROM dbo_VehicleStatusReport) - 3000

Comment: he can simply add `> ((SELECT max(StatusReportID) FROM dbo_VehicleStatusReport) - 3000)`

Comment: You don't have to post the fix as a separate query, just edit the original query so that it meets the requirement, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT MaxSRID = MAX(StatusReportID) - 3000 
  FROM dbo_VehicleStatusReport
)
SELECT v.StatusReportID, v.StatusReportTime, ... 
FROM dbo_VehicleStatusReport AS v
INNER JOIN x
ON v.StatusReportID > x.MaxSRID;
```

If the goal is to find the newest 2999 entries, then the following is much simpler and more reliable:

```
SELECT TOP (2999) StatusReportID, StatusReportTime, ...
FROM dbo_VehicleStatusReport
ORDER BY StatusReportTime DESC;
```

This is because:

1. `IDENTITY` values can be lost through deletes and rollbacks, so the query that relies on `MAX - 3000` might not necessarily yield 2999 rows.
2. `IDENTITY` columns can be reseeded and values can be overridden, so assuming that increasing values mean later could be problematic.

Comment: this is a great and elegant solution!